# Is there a good way to index a lot of data in a smart contract to be able to read it efficiently?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am writing a solidity smart contract in which users would be able add a string (eg. one line joke), and other users should be able to vote on these jokes. If there are for example a million jokes in the contract (all with a different vote count), Would it be possible to rank these jokes by vote count? Eg. display the highest voted 10 of the million jokes? I know it is possible on a small scale, but on a larger scale I'm not so sure.

Comment: not a good idea. Augur platform released the coolest nicest platform to make predictions about things, but the costs to trade are within 100-300 bucks per transaction. This is completely unusable, so will your contract, it is going to be unusable due to transaction costs. When you write your contract, always check the cost of operating it (by multiplying gas spent by gas price)

Comment: also, calculate the costs of uploading the data to the MainNet. I have seen proposals that required millions of dollars to make initial DB population and this would stop the MainNet from operating for a few months

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say these jokes are posted one at a time, each user pays a small amount of gas to publish the joke (eg. max length 255). So they are really just adding a small string to a mapping, not super costly. But my concern is with reading the data and sorting/filtering it. If the mapping would contain le'ts say a million jokes. Could these be sorted in the frontend without any external servers or do you think it's impossible? thanks

Comment: Overall, there is no need to store strings in blockchain, especially large scale. You need to architecture your solution differently and store hashes of strings, or some other pointers to outside data.

Comment: Thing is, I wanted to create an entirely decentralized backend. Any suggestions on the architecture or other technologies I could use?

Comment: yeah, storing hashes of strings is a good idea, this is how Ethreum Name Service (ENS) works. You don't register a domain name, you are registering a hash. However this solution will make your application centralized because to download the joke strings we would need your server to be online

Comment: check IPFS for decentralized backend, may work for you

Comment: sorting 1 million jokes 255 long each will require 243 MB of RAM. A bubble sort will sort this thing in 10 seconds on an old Android of release date 5 years ago.

Comment: Thank you, this comment was super helpful. Decentralization is way more important to me than a small waiting time :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of the contract that implements the main functionality you need is attached below:

- registration of "jokes" records
- registration of voting without repeats
- definition of the top 10 (I hope I was not mistaken in the sorting algorithm).

The hash from its text is used as the identifier of the "joke".

However, in order to provide users with quality functionality, you need an external application that will monitor the events **JokeCreated** and **JokeVoted** of this contract and maintain an external database of "jokes" records.
This is because Ethereum contracts are ineffective for iterative operations with large arrays and you need an external service to:

- providing users with a common list of "jokes"
- providing users with a general rating list of "jokes"
  When using an external application, you can also exclude the function of determining the top 10 from the contract (in function **VotesForJoke**), which will significantly reduce the cost of the voting transaction.
  In addition, you need to keep in mind the problem of identifying users to avoid re-voting, since in general it cannot be solved at the level of Ethereum itself.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract Jokes
{

    struct Joke 
    {
         string                 text ;
        address                 sender ;
        bytes32                 author ;
        uint256                 votes ;
        mapping (bytes32=>bool) voters ;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => Joke)  JokesList ;
                  bytes32[10]  Top10 ;

    event JokeCreated(bytes32 hash, string text, address sender, bytes32  author) ; 
    event JokeVoted  (bytes32 hash, bytes32 voter) ; 

    constructor() public
    {
    }

   function NewJoke(string  memory text_, bytes32  author_) public 
   {
       bytes32  hash ;
    
            hash=keccak256(abi.encodePacked(text_)) ;

       if(JokesList[hash].author!=0x00)  require(false) ;

         JokesList[hash] =Joke({   text: text_, 
                                 sender: tx.origin,
                                 author: author_,
                                  votes: 0         }) ;

      emit JokeCreated(hash, text_, tx.origin, author_) ; 
   }


   function VotesForJoke(bytes32  hash_, bytes32  voter_) public 
   {
      uint256  votes ;
      uint256  i ;

// Check for existance
       if(JokesList[hash_].author==0x00)  require(false) ;
// Check for re-voting
       if(JokesList[hash_].voters[voter_]==true)  require(false) ;

          JokesList[hash_].voters[voter_]=true ;
          JokesList[hash_].votes++ ;

// Ordering top 10
            votes=JokesList[hash_].votes ;

        for(i=9 ; i>=0 ; i--)
          if(votes>=JokesList[Top10[i]].votes)
          {
              if(i!=9 && Top10[i]!=hash_)  Top10[i+1]=Top10[i] ;
          }
          else
          {
               break ;  
          }

          if(i!=9)  Top10[i+1]=hash_ ;

// Emit event of voting
      emit JokeVoted(hash_, voter_) ; 
   }

   function GetJoke(bytes32  hash_) public view returns (string memory, address, bytes32,uint256 retVal)
   {
        return(JokesList[hash_].text, JokesList[hash_].sender, JokesList[hash_].author, JokesList[hash_].votes) ;
   }

   function GetTop10() public view returns (bytes32[10] memory retVal)
   {
       return(Top10) ;
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, sadly, this is was what I was afraid of: " This is because Ethereum contracts are ineffective for iterative operations".  The plan was to create a website or application that was not dependent on external servers. I want users to be able to search in the jokes and sort them based on votes,.. but sadly like you said that would be ineffective. Thanks anyways for your answer.